# Play with Akka Logging

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, logback, playframework-2.3

I'm using the Play Actor System to run a few actors. I'd like to add logging which is sent to files, but for whatever reason it isn't working. Here are the details:

My actors roughly look like this:

```
package actors

class My Actor() extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    def receice = {
        case Foo => log.info("Foo was sent")
    }
}
```

application.conf:

```
akka {
    logLevel = "DEBUG"
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    debug {
        autoreceive = on
        lifecycle = on
    }
}
```

I have added in my build.sbt file:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.3.11"
```

And as documented [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger) I added this to my logger.xml:

```
<logger name="akka" level="INFO" />
```

My logger.xml file is otherwise a copy of the default configuration for play.

How can I get logging working properly for my actors? STDOUT isn't even working in this case.

I dont wan't to use `play.api.Logger` since it blocks.

Comment: Could it be because of typo? `loglevel` in lowercase. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/logging.html

Comment: Which logger implementation are you using? slf4j  is actually an interface so you also need to include something like log4j or logback.

Comment: @MonCalamari that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Bob Play already comes with an implementation - Logback. In fact, all regular Play logging is writing to file. I still tried adding Logback in my sbt file, and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What does your logback configuration file look like?

Comment: As I've said, its the default configuration (you can find it [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger)) with `<logger name="akka" level="INFO" />` added.

Comment: try to add `loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger"]` instead of loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]. Is it prints anything to stdout?